# Nginx - redirect all "checkout" traffic to https?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to ensure that no one can go through the checkout process without https. How can I redirect anything that starts with /checktout (i.e. example.com/checkout & example.com/checkout/process) to https if it's not.

Vice versa, I don't want any page to be able to be accessed through https *unless* it has /checkout. So anything else should be redirected to http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use static location:

```
server {
        listen   80 default;
        server_name  example.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;

        location / {
                root   /var/www/example.com;
        }

        location /checkout {
                rewrite         ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 redirect;
        }
}

server {
    listen   443;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
            rewrite         ^/(.*)$ http://example.comt/$1 redirect;
    }

    location /checkout {
            root /var/www/example.com/checkout;
    }

    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate  myssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  myssl.key;

}
```

Comment: Correct approach, though you can use $request_uri or $uri to avoid the capture in your redirects.

Comment: I like static location, because they are easy to add and edit